# OpenCV Failed to Import outside the root directory using anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

**Steps to reproduce the error:**

I have just installed OpenCV on my new Conda environment (Python 3.7.11) using :

```
conda install opencv
```

Everything went well. Conda was downloading and extracting some other packages, including **numpy-1.21.2.** The installed **opencv** version is **3.4.2**

I tried to run this code from my terminal, from the root directory.

```
python
>> import cv2
>> cv2.__version__
```

Still running smoothly. Python prints the cv2 version. But there is an errorwhen I run the same code from another directory (e.g. : `~/Downloads`). The error is :

```
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 07:03:16)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

**More Weird Errors**

When I run the same code directly from vscode and select the same conda environment in the vscode, the same problems appear in the vscode terminal. Even more, when I try to type `python` from the vscode terminal, it shows python 2.7

```
 │  ~  source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate                                                                       1 ✘ │ base  │ 08:09:48 PM  

  │  ~  conda activate testenvi                                                                                    ✔ │ base  │ 08:09:48 PM  

  │  ~  python -u "/Users/martinmanullang/Downloads/testsiopencv.py"                                           ✔ │ testenvi  │ 08:09:49 PM  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/martinmanullang/Downloads/testsiopencv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2

  │  ~  python                                                                                               1 ✘ │ testenvi  │ 08:09:53 PM  

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.18 (default, Oct  2 2021, 04:20:39) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.1) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploymen on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

**Some steps that I already tried:**

- Reinstalling opencv with `pip install opencv-contrib-python`
- Reinstalling numpy (with pip, with conda)
- Create new env with python 3.5,3.6,3.9

Nothing works. Kindly need help from you guys.

**System Specification**

- MacbookPro 2020 running macOS Monterey
- VSCode 1.61.2
- iTerm 3.4.12 with ZSH

Comment: Can you check which python you are using in the root directory? And whether you can find the `cv2` folder in the `conda` environment? It looks like you need to reinstall the `numpy` in the `conda` environment. And could you run the python file directly in the terminal instead of the `Code Runer`?

Comment: Python in Root : 3.7.11 (using iTerm)
Python in non-root : 3.7.11 (using iTerm)

'where python' shows :

/opt/anaconda3/envs/testenvi/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

and yes, I have the cv2 folder inside:
/opt/anaconda3/envs/testenvi/include/opencv2

Comment: Sorry for being late. From the second part of the codes, it looks like you have installed the `opencv` in an aconda environment, but I can't get which aconda environment it is.  Could you attach some pictures with the full information? Includes the terminal in the root directory and out of the root directory, and in the VSCode, except your names please do not hide info, then I can not know which environment you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have activated the conda environment. Its name will be added at the head of the command line. Then when you search the python command, the python executable in the activated environment will be the first one.

[image]

And you can find the `opencv` module with the command of pip show `opencv-python`.

[image]

From the second code in your question. It looks like your `numpy` module has some problem, Could you try to reinstall(`pip install -U numpy`) it? And could you upgrade your opencv with the command of `pip install -U opencv-python`? Because my version of cv2 was `4.5.4-dev`, and it works well.

Comment: Many thanks for considering my problems. I've upgraded everything using pip to the latest version and tried again to import cv2 (from the root and inside a directory), but the problem still appears. Kindly check this attachment. https://imgur.com/a/JJwaw0w

Comment: @amisotcm Sorry for being late. Could you out of the `Download` folder? Because I have a doubt of you have a python executable in the `Download` folder. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @amisotcm Hi, do you still?

Comment: I think the problem is fixed, let me update the screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/KtV51sD) Thank you @Steven-MSFT

Comment: @amisotcm Glad to hear that.

Comment: @amisotcm You have a python installation program in the `Download` folder, isn't it?

Comment: not sure since my Downloads are full of stuff, and I have just installed conda in recent weeks. I was guessing that conda caused all this mess. Previously I relied on pyenv.

Comment: @amisotcm Agree with that, it's a complex folder, need keep away from it. haha.